# Pulling out Keys and Values from an hash of arrays

Tags: ruby

I have an hash like this -

```
    {"examples"=>
      [{"year"=>1999,
            "provider"=>{"name"=>"abc", "id"=>711},
            "url"=> "http://example.com/1",
            "reference"=>"abc",
            "text"=> "Sample text 1",
            "title"=> "Sample Title 1",
            "documentId"=>30091286,
            "exampleId"=>786652043,
            "rating"=>357.08115},
        {"year"=>1999,
            "provider"=>{"name"=>"abc", "id"=>3243},
            "url"=> "http://example.com/2",
            "reference"=>"dec",
            "text"=> "Sample text 2",
            "title"=> "Sample Title 2",
            "documentId"=>30091286,
            "exampleId"=>786652043,
        "rating"=>357.08115},
        {"year"=>1999,
            "provider"=>{"name"=>"abc", "id"=>191920},
            "url"=> "http://example.com/3",
            "reference"=>"wer",
            "text"=> "Sample text 3",
            "title"=> "Sample Title 3",
            "documentId"=>30091286,
            "exampleId"=>786652043,
        "rating"=>357.08115}]
}
```

and I would like to create a new array by pulling out the keys, and values for just the "text", "url" and "title" keys like below.

```
   [
     {"text"=> "Sample text 1", "title"=> "Sample Title 1", "url"=> "http://example.com/1"},
     {"text"=> "Sample text 2", "title"=> "Sample Title 2", "url"=> "http://example.com/2"},
     {"text"=> "Sample text 3", "title"=> "Sample Title 3", "url"=> "http://example.com/3"}
   ]
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You may want *array of hash*, as inner arrays are not valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do as

```
hash['examples'].map do |hash|
    keys = ["text", "title", "url"]
    keys.zip(hash.values_at(*keys)).to_h
end
```

If you are below < 2.1 use,

```
 Hash[keys.zip(hash.values_at(*keys))]
```

Comment: You always come up with the most concise ways to handle these situations. Very nice work. Although since he did not specify a version maybe post a version without `to_h` in case he's not running > 2.0

Comment: Worked like a charm. @engineersmnky - I am also using Ruby 2.0 so thanks for the < 2.1 suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way this could be done (where `h` is the hash given in the question).

```
KEEPERS = ['text','url','title']

h.each_key.with_object({}) { |k,g|
  g[k] = h[k].map { |h| h.select { |sk,_| KEEPERS.include? sk } } }
    #=> {"examples"=>[
    #     [{"url"=>"http://example.com/1", "text"=>"Sample text 1",
    #       "title"=>"Sample Title 1"},
    #      {"url"=>"http://example.com/2", "text"=>"Sample text 2",
    #       "title"=>"Sample Title 2"},
    #      {"url"=>"http://example.com/3", "text"=>"Sample text 3",
    #       "title"=>"Sample Title 3"}]}
```

Here we simply create a new hash (denoted by the outer block variable `g`) which has all the keys of the original hash `h` (just one, `"examples"`, but there could be more), and for each associated value, which is an array of hashes, we use [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [Hash#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-select) to retain only the desired key/value pairs from each of those hashes.